# Weird Mesh/UV problem cant seem to fix it

Tags: mesh, materials, uv

I have a model of a Opel Blitz: Maultier and im facing a problem, the meshes or something seem to be duplicated or somehow bugging in a weird way. Quick clip: [Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5GHf.jpg)

Same problem in 3ds Max 2020, if somebody wants the files i can provide them if needed.

i already tried to remove materials and i tried to see if i can do something with the meshes but no luck.. didn't find a way. These weird spots appear and when i remove it the second material it seems to be fixed but its not because when i check in 3ds max it still breaks.

In blender i can see this:
[image]

Download: [Link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/zgav03vaqkaz2p8/opel.blend/file)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about 3ds studio.

Comment: Excuse me but its also about Blender because i have a problem there too. @brockmann

Comment: @Stahlhelm_TV, please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/167356/edit) your question and clarify your question as it is not currently clear that it is specifically about blender. Adding more images/ information within the content of your question rather than external links to videos will greatly help the clarity of your question.

Comment: I checked your file. The mesh has two materials with random assignment. You just need to remove one of them or assign with reasonable regions, if you want to keep both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick look and I figure it out.

Every mesh has two materials applied.

Deleting one of them will solve the problem.

The bad news is: You must repeat it with every mesh.

[image: Double material]

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback, sadly i have a already tried that it works in blender but as soon as i put it into 3ds Max it breaks still..

Comment: After altering all meshes just export to obj. I think it will solve it.

Comment: How do you mean alter all meshes? i mean i can delete the materials and try .obj but how do you mean i should alter all meshes?

Comment: I mean correcting the materials.